# IE10, Iframe and PHP SESSION var

Tags: php, iframe, session-variables, internet-explorer-10

I have a form with a captcha on a web page, this captcha is using (as all capcha I think) SESSION variables to store the value.
This form is working with IE7-8 and 9, also with FF, Chrome, Safari etc. but with **IE10** I have a problem.
If this form is directly called on the webpage of IE10 the captcha code works well, but if this form is called from an **IFRAME** of another website, SESSION variables are not stored. No way to use SESSION variables in this case.

Any idea ?

Comment: If your code works on IE9 and below just not on IE10 there is a good chance that it is due to IE10's DoNotTrack setting being turned on by default thus blocking cookies from being shared in any way: http://econsultancy.com/ca/blog/10983-thanks-microsoft-do-not-track-is-effectively-dead-on-arrival Needless to say there is a lot of concern with this setting being turned on by default as sites are now ignoring it.

Comment: I tried to remove the "do-not-track", but have the same problem. In fact, using the form directly (without an Iframe from another domain), the form is working good in IE10.
I will try with this hack : sending a special Http header :  P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"

A let you know

Answer (score 0):

iframes are subject to their contents' originating site. Since you're loading the captcha/form from some other site, any cookies set in that frame are locked down to that other site.

e.g. your site is example.com. the iframe comes from foobar.net. Any cookies set in the iframe are restricted to foobar.net and will not be available to example.com.

Comment: I understand, but in this case, the website "foobar.net" is displaying an IFRAME pointing to "example.com" where the form **AND** the Captcha are hosted... same domaine and same server... This form is functionning from the IFRAME with FF,IE7-8-9,Chrome,Opera,Safari,Konkeror, etc... NOT IE10 !!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are confusing sessions and cookies. A session is stored on the server, a cookie on the client. If you have a session you will like have a cookie that identifies your session. So really you're talking about cookies.

You are not allowed to fetch cookies from another domain. It violates the same-origin-policy.

If you control both domains there is a possibility to set up resource sharing (CORS Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing), but it's not very easy.

Comment: I don't confuse sessions and cookies, I really know what it is I'm a webcoder and make complex websites.

It concerne the SESSION Cookie called "PHPSESSID" (for PHP coding) and not a user cookie. This SESSION cookie is sent by the browser to identify the same visitor during the visit. By storing informations with this ID, PHP can retrieve variables previously stored in different pages of the same webiste (same domain) and the same browser. (see http://www.php.net)
A user Cookie is stored even if you close the navigator, a SESSION cookie is lost if you close your navigator (not the tab ...).

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in IE10. See [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/792123/cookie-not-sent-during-ajax-call-of-a-page-inside-an-iframe#details).

Comment: Consider improve your answer with some description of your reference content.